# Detecting Arrow Up/Down in a Shell

Tags: c++, shell, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to implement a shell for a uni project using Flex/Bison and C++.

For extra points, we're invited to implement a history using the up/down arrow keys. I'm struggling a bit with detecting the arrow keys.

I think doing this within flex is a bit outside of the scope of flex but using the `getch()` methods I have found on other posts also doesn't work, since if the user were to type something other than an up/down arrow key, I'd lose the first character of my input.

I'd love some pointers as to where I can find information on how to do this neatly. Since it's for uni, I'm not asking for a fully worked out answer. :)

Comment: You need to configure the terminal to send raw keypresses to your shell.

Comment: As for parsing the command lines, I suggest you do it on a line.based basis, using the full lines only after the `Enter` key has been pressed. Doing parsing and lexing with embedded editing of the line is going to be hard, and make your code very complicated.

Comment: why don't you just use the readline library?

Comment: @rici I could but doing the implementation myself is more in spirit with the course and also seems to be most fun.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, we first have to find out the ASCII values of the arrow keys, which are the following:

```
Up Arrow    - 72
Down Arrow  - 80
Left Arrow  - 75
Right Arrow - 77
```

Now we can easily check for keypress as follows:

```
if (character == char(72))
{
    std::cout << "Up arrow pressed!";
}
else if (character == char(80))
{
    std::cout << "Down arrow pressed!";
}
```

Note I used the following here in order to convert ASCII value to char:

```
char(ascii_value)
```

### Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main() 
{
    while (true)
    {
        char character = _getch();
    
        if (character == char(72))
        {
            std::cout << "Up arrow pressed!"; break; // Up arrow pressed
        }
        else if (character == char(80))
        {
            std::cout << "Down arrow pressed!"; break; // Down arrow pressed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "ASCII codes" for keyboard arrow keys? "Key scan code" is better. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170#remarks